# C# Expression API - Capture outer variable

Tags: c#, expression

I am currently testing Expression API and I am strugling to create an expression (using Expression API) similar to the following:

```
Expression<Func<string>> SomeFunction(string a)
{
      return () => a;
}
```

My ideia is this function, instead of a "hardcoded" expression, would be using the Expression API. So far I got this working:

```
Expression<Func<string>> cache = null; 
Expression<Func<string>> SomeFunction2(string a)
{
    if(cache != null)
        return cache;
    var aVariable = Expression.Constant(a, typeof(string));
    cache = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(aVariable);
    return cache;
}
```

The problem with the above example is, since I captuire the variable as a constant, the second time I call this method, it will not work as expected. How can I create an expression using the scope variable? Is this kind of thing even possible?

Comment: Have you tried reverse-inspecting what exactly the compiler generates in the first case? I mean, using a Quick Watch for example.

Comment: Also, `string` type is handled like a struct - try using some other reference type. Or may be you're trying to capture the `ref` version of the parameter? The pointer, that is?

Comment: _"it will not work as expected."_ - And what do you expect here to happen?

Comment: I guess it also looks like you can benefit from *Source Generators*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=.NET+Source+Generators

Comment: @AgentFire _"`string` type is handled like a struct"_? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I don't understand what your actual problem is, but my wild guess would be that you are creating one cache record for all different `a`'s which can be passed into your method. So for every one you will get the same expression generated for first. Your cache should be of type `Dicitionary<string. Func<string>>` (or better `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<string>>`) with corresponding changes to the code. As for the expression generated - I would say you are generating one quite right.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment. If I udnerstood your problem correctly - try something like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Expression<Func<string>>> cache = new(); // using concurrent one JIC, dependent on your usecase can be an overkill
public Expression<Func<string>> SomeFunction2(string a)
{
    if(cache.TryGetValue(a, out var value))
        return value;
    var aVariable = Expression.Constant(a, typeof(string));
    var res  = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(aVariable);
    cache.TryAdd(a, res);
    return res;
}
```